# Coordinate transformation in ODE's with a unit step function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

Consider the following general set of 2 ODE's

$$\dot{x}=\Theta(\dot{x} )f_1(x,y)+(1-\Theta(\dot{x}))f_2(x,y)$$
$$\dot{y}=(1-\Theta(\dot{y}))g_1(x,y)+\Theta(\dot{y})g_2(x,y)$$

where $\Theta(x)$ is the unit step function.

what it means is when $\dot{x}>0$ then the dynamics are govern by $f_1$ and when $\dot{x}<0$ then the dynamics are govern by $f_2$. With $\dot{y}$ it is the other way around.

Now let's consider that I can make in $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$ the transformations
$x-y\rightarrow d$ and $y-y\rightarrow 0$, which leaves me with

$$\dot{x}=\Theta(\dot{x} )f_1(d)+(1-\Theta(\dot{x}))f_2(d)$$
$$\dot{y}=(1-\Theta(\dot{y}))g_1(d)+\Theta(\dot{y})g_2(d)$$

I would like to apply the transformation over the derivatives, such that I get an equation for $\dot{d}$ as well

$$\dot{d}=\dot{x}-\dot{y}=\Theta(\dot{x} )f_1(d)+(1-\Theta(\dot{x}))f_2(d)-(1-\Theta(\dot{y}))g_1(d)-\Theta(\dot{y})g_2(d)$$

If I apply the transformation on the unit step function as well, it seems that I lose information about the system

$$\dot{d}=\Theta(\dot{d} )f_1(d)+(1-\Theta(\dot{d}))f_2(d)-(1-\Theta(0))g_1(d)-\Theta(0)g_2(d)$$

The unit step can be defined when $\Theta(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ or $\Theta(0)=1$. In both cases I lose the information about $\dot{y}$.

Is there any way to make a transformation of such a system to $\dot{d}$?

Comment: You lost information when you redefined $f_1(x,y) \to f_1(x-y)$, which isn't always true.

Comment: @Dylan, I assume here that the functional form of $f_1$ can do so, for example, $f_1(x,y)=4(x-y)+e^{x-y}$.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking? Solve the reduced system for $d$, then plug it back into the original equations of $\dot x$ and $\dot y$

Comment: @Dylan, yes but when you substitute $x\rightarrow x-y=d$ and $y\rightarrow y-y=0$ you end up with $\Theta(\dot{y}) \rightarrow \Theta(0)$ and lose the sign of the derivative which is also dynamic.

Comment: That should tell you that the substitution isn't valid. You can't reduce one variable to $0$ without justifying it.

Comment: @Dylan, so what I'm asking here, if anyone has some experience or expertise on dealing with such transformation, and can recognize how to deal with the unit step function such that the transformation will be valid.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd say it's probably because $\Theta(x) - \Theta(y) \ne \Theta(x-y)$.